# SQL add to already existing value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a **value** in my MYSQL database, all I want to do is to **increase the current value with a new one**, this is what I have tried

```
    } elseif ($gametype == "veckanskluring"){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET veckanskluring='veckanskluring'+'$score' WHERE id='$id'";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $link );
        echo "GAME == $gametype";
}
```

But for some odd reason, this won't work.
I have searched online and found examples, but they all look, almost exactly the same as my code.

// **Sidenote** this is not the whole code, obviously. 
Everything except the part where I add the new value to the old value works, and if I remove 'veckanskluring'+ it updates without any problems. 
I strongly believe something is wrong with this part - 'veckanskluring'+ as the other part works fine. 
//**NOTE2** score is always 999, just have it set to $score if I want to change it later.

UPDATE -

**MY fault, apparently I had put '' around veckanskluring.**

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET veckanskluring=veckanskluring +'$score' WHERE id='$id'"; <-- Working.
```

Comment: You only need quotes in your SQL statements round literal values, not column names (they become strings) or numeric values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $score and $id are number  you shoudl not use sigle quote around this vars

and assuming that veckanskluring is column name you must not use single quote aroud column name

```
"UPDATE users SET veckanskluring= veckanskluring +$score WHERE id=$id";
```

But the use of php var in sql is deprecated  you at risk for sql injection .. take a look at your mysql driver for bindig param